# how to find the string starting with @ in the xml files through unix

Tags: unix

I have the different xml files at the following directory  `/opt/app/rty/servers/tr/current/ops/config`

Let's say there are three files named

```
abc.xml
bv.xml
ert.xml
```

Now inside these xml there can be many tags as like shown below

```
<bean id="sdrt" class="com.interfaces.send.erty">                   
    <property name="eprocDependentOnClientAddress"><value>@argon.tdw.client.address@</value></property>
    <property name="eprocDependentOnClientAddressEod"><value>tyu</value></property>                 
</bean>
```

Now my objective is that inside directory /opt/app/rty/servers/tr/current/ops/config I need to search in all xml files and have to find that in every xml in context to property tag there should be no value starting from @ tag and also ending with @ tag

Let's say for example in the above xml file the below is correct

```
<property name="eprocDependentOnClientAddressEod"><value>tyu</value></property>
```

but the below is not correct

```
<property name="eprocDependentOnClientAddress"><value>@argon.tdw.client.address@</value></property>
```

so please advise what will be the command in unix to search the files names that is those xml in which there is a tag starting with @ inside the property tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find files have `<value>@` and `@</value>` strings in content, use this shell

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in `ls *.xml`; do
a=`egrep  -o "<value>@"\|"@</value>" $line`
    if [[ "$a" == "<value>@"* && "$a" == *"@</value>" ]]; then
        printf "File  $line has issues.\n"
    else
        printf "File  $line is clean.\n"
    fi
done
```

And if `@` needs to replaced from within `<value>` tag.

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in `ls *.xml`; do
a=`egrep  -o "<value>@"\|"@</value>" $line`
    if [[ "$a" == "<value>@"* && "$a" == *"@</value>" ]]; then
        printf 'File  $line has issues.\n'
        sed -e 's/<value>@//g' -e 's/@<\/value>//g' $line > ${line}.replaced
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks a lot also please advise that as shown above that before @ starts there must be tag as <value> and after @ tag there will be tag as </value> so we can modify the script as per that also

Comment: Edited the code to be more aligned with requirements. Hope this helps.

Comment: Also one change in above script should be that it should take the directory location as input please advise how to this

Comment: for full path `ls /opt/app/rty/servers/tr/current/ops/config/*.xml`  would suffice in for loop. same script can be a single liner , just need ; after every step. :)

Comment: If you think this answer has solved or answered your question properly. Please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)? for more information